# Adding self link to projection in spring data rest

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have a simple application containing Products, Prices and PricedProducts.

When I request the list of PricedProducts, I want the Price and the Product to be inlined. I marked my Price repository with @RestResource(exported = false), so for this one it works ok. Products, however, need to be self standing entities (I need to be able to build several PricedProducts using the same Product for example).

I created a projection for PricedProduct, added it as excerptProjection, and a GET to /pricedProducts returns:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "pricedProducts": [
      {
        "price": {
          "value": "100.50",
          "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "product": {
          "name": "Poatato",
          "description": null,
          "pictureUrl": null
        },
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1"
          },
          "pricedProduct": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
          },
          "product": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1/product"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/profile/pricedProducts"
    }
  }
}
```

This inlines my product, however it does not supply a self link for it. So in my client app, when somebody edits the name of the product, for example, I don't know which product I must update, unless I do an extra request.

What I did next was to create a projection for Product, which I use inside the projection for PricedProduct. A GET to /pricedProducts now yields:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "pricedProducts": [
      {
        "price": {
          "value": "100.50",
          "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "product": {
          "pictureUrl": null,
          "description": null,
          "name": "Potato",
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/products/1{?projection}",
              "templated": true
            }
          }
        },
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1"
          },
          "pricedProduct": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
          },
          "product": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1/product"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/profile/pricedProducts"
    }
  }
}
```

Now my Product has a self link, but it points to its projection (http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/products/1{?projection}). What I want is:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "pricedProducts": [
      {
        "price": {
          "value": "100.50",
          "currency": "RON"
        },
        "product": {
          "pictureUrl": null,
          "description": null,
          "name": "Potato",
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/products/1
            }
          }
        },
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1"
          },
          "pricedProduct": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
          },
          "product": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts/1/product"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/pricedProducts"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1.0/profile/pricedProducts"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest, and more correct, thing to do is using a child projection and parse the self link on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit old question, but I faced the same problem today and I found a solution:

All you have to do is to REMOVE the `@Projection` annotation from the embedded projection (ProductProjection) which is used inside the top level projection (PricedProductProjection).

Of course, in this case you cannot use that projection in GET queries, but I assume you don't even need it. (It was created especially for this purpose)